# How to use multiple equal to queries in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to return all items in a list where their ID is equal to an ID from an array.  I run the following code:

```
for (ss in sets) {
    query.equalTo("setsID", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Sets",
        objectId: sets[ss].objectId});
}
```

The issue is that I only get results from the last set of items.  It's like the equalTo gets overwritten each time.  Is there a better way to configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working by creating a temporary query and using the Parse.Query.or method to combine the queries.

```
for(ss in sets){
    tempQuery.equalTo("setsID", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Sets",
        objectId: sets[ss].objectId});
    query = Parse.Query.or(query, tempQuery);
}
```